# Ansible jinja2 templating

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

In Ansible, I currently have vars set out like this

```
    container_a_version: 1
    container_b_version: 6
    container_c_version: 3
    container_d_version: 2
    ...
```

```
    containers:
     - container_a
     - container_b
     - container_c
     - container_d  
    ...
```

Each container has its own template file which has a line like this

```
    image: registry.sportpesa.com/sportpesa/global/container-a:{{ container_a_version }}
```

My playbook

```
    - name: Copy templates
      template:
        src: templates/docker-compose-{{ item }}.yml
        dest: /srv/docker-compose-{{ item }}.yml
      loop: "{{ containers }}"
```

If I want to deploy only container a and c. I change my variable to this

```
    containers:
     - container_a
    # - container_b
     - container_c
    # - container_d
```

What I want to do condense my variables to just have 1 var like this

```
    containers:
      - { name: a, version: 1 }
      - { name: b, version: 6 }
      - { name: c, version: 3 }
      - { name: d, version: 2 }
```

However I'm not sure how I can call the container version in my template. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    containers:
      - {name: a, version: 1}
      - {name: b, version: 2}
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: containers.txt.j2
        dest: containers.txt
```

and the template

```yaml
shell> cat containers.txt.j2
{% for item in containers %}
name: {{ item.name }} version {{ item.version }}
{% endfor %}
```

give

```yaml
shell> cat containers.txt
name: a version 1
name: b version 2
```

---

It's possible to iterate the list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "image: registry.example.com/container-{{ item.name }}:container_{{ item.version }}_version"
      loop: "{{ containers }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 'image: registry.example.com/container-a:container_1_version'
  msg: 'image: registry.example.com/container-b:container_2_version'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want two different templates, each with it's respective container name and version without looping the `containers` variable. You can use a playbook that renders two templates. In my example I will call the templates:

- container-a
- container-b

The template `container-a.j2`:

```
image: registry.example.com/container-{{ containers[0]['name'] }}:{{ containers[0]['version'] }}
```

The template `container-b.j2`:

```
image: registry.example.com/container-{{ containers[1]['name'] }}:{{ containers[1]['version'] }}
```

Then my playbook will have below tasks:

```yaml
vars:
  containers:
  - { name: a, version: 1 }
  - { name: b, version: 2 }

tasks:
- template:
    src: "container-{{ containers[0]['name'] }}.j2"
    dest: "/tmp/container-{{ containers[0]['name'] }}"
- template:
    src: "container-{{ containers[1]['name'] }}.j2"
    dest: "/tmp/container-{{ containers[1]['name'] }}"
```

When this playbook is run, it renders `/tmp/container-a`:

```
image: registry.example.com/container-a:1
```

and `/tmp/container-b`:

```
image: registry.example.com/container-b:2
```